# Polymorphism with overrides and base calls simulating an employee

Tags: c, polymorphism

I've studied and worked a lot on the subject for a month or two to get closer to the concept in a cleaner way, i.e. no virtual tables and no bunch of functions with prefixes etc. and most importantly functions are to be defined within structs as pointers to simulate OOP classes as much as possible.

Only constructors with prefixes are to be available publically. I also wanted to have the ability to call the override super method.

I'm not sure if following example is a compile time or run time polymorphism but it's satisfying the runtime aspects of it but then isn't it what we need without the need to have a look at the type of object? Please enlighten.

I'm putting it out there for critical analysis and review or problem with the approach.

The idea is to introduce a pointer of the parent type that retains a reference to original methods, the sub structures can override the parent implementation of the methods but the call to original methods are available via base pointer.

**main.c**

```
int main() {
    Person* person = Person_new("John", "Doe");
    Employee* employee = Employee_new("Jane", "Doe", "Acme", 40000);
    person->display(person); // displaying Person object
    puts("------");
    employee->super.display(&employee->super); // displaying employee info
    // ((Person *)employee)->display(employee); // or this
    person->release(person);
    employee->super.release(&employee->super);
    return 0;
}
```

**person.h**

```
typedef struct Person Person;
struct Person {
    Person *base; // to keep access to original funcs in case of overrides
    char* first;
    char* last;
    void (*display)(const Person *self);
    void (*release)(Person *self);
};
Person* Person_new(char* first, char* last);
```

**person.c**

```
static void display(const Person *self) {
    printf("First: %s\n", self->first);
    printf("Last: %s\n", self->last);
}

static void release(Person *self) {
    free(self);
}

Person* Person_new(char* first, char* last) {
    Person* self = malloc(sizeof *self);
    if(self == NULL) return NULL;

    self->first = strdup(first);
    self->last = strdup(last);
    self->display = display;
    self->release = release;

    self->base = self; // assigning reference to self to retain original functions in case they get overridden

    return self;
}
```

**employee.h**

```
typedef struct Employee Employee;
struct Employee {
    Person super;
    char* company;
    int salary;
};
Employee* Employee_new(char* first, char* last, char* company, int salary);
```

**employee.c**

```
static void display(const Person* self) {
    self->base->display(self->base); // calling super class func

    printf("Company: %s\n", ((Employee *)self)->company);
    printf("Salary: %d\n", ((Employee*)self)->salary);
}

static void release(Person *self) {
    self->base->release(self->base); // calling super class func
    free(self);
}

Employee* Employee_new(char* first, char* last, char* company, int salary) {
    Employee* employee = malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    if(employee == NULL) return NULL;

    employee->super = *Person_new(first, last);
    employee->super.display = display; // override
    employee->super.release = release; // override

    employee->company = strdup(company);
    employee->salary = salary;

    return employee;
}
```

> ```
> First: John
> Last: Doe
> ---
> First: Jane
> Last: Doe
> Company: Acme
> Salary: 40000
> ```

**Edit**

Discussion with Pablo confirmed that the approach is correct. I'm still seeking some discussion on whether this approach falls under compile time or run time polymorphism.

Comment: This `malloc(sizeof(char *) * (strlen(first) + 1));` is incorrect, it should be `sizeof(char)` which is defined to be 1, so you can just do `malloc(strlen(first) + 1)`. And check the return value of `malloc`!

Comment: Even `malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(last) + 1));` is debatable to if that is the preferable code.  Rolling post post to OP's original to avoid a moving review target.

Comment: Your second edit with the free is wrong, see my answer, I've updated it addressing that. You cannot free something and access it afterwards, and `&employee->super` does not return the address of the original pointer.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please don't change or add to the code in your question after you have received answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one thing I don't line about `Employee`: you are leaking memory.

`Person super;` should be a pointer, not the object. You are creating the
object with `malloc`, by doing

```
    employee->super = *Person_new(first, last);
```

you are leaking memory because you lose the reference of the pointer returned
by `malloc` and you cannot free it when you destroy the object. And you are not
checking if `malloc` is returning 0. So I'd change it to:

```
typedef struct Employee Employee;
struct Employee {
    Person super;
    char* company;
    int salary;
    Person *super_ref;
};

Person* Employee_new(char* first, char* last, char* company, int salary) {
    Employee* employee = malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    if(employee == NULL)
        return NULL;

    employee->super_ref = *Person_new(first, last);
    if(employee->super_ref == NULL)
    {
        free(employee);
        return NULL;
    }

    employee->super = *employee->super_ref;
    employee->super.display = display; // override

    employee->company = company;
    employee->salary = salary;

    return (Person *)employee;
}
```

so now the destroy method can do `free(obj->super_ref);` to free the memory of
the base object.

**edit**

An alternative is that you create a init function for `Person` objects that gets
an object as an argument and does not allocate memory by itself. I'd do:

```
int Person_init(Person *self, char* first, char* last))
{
    if(self == NULL || first == NULL || last == NULL)
        return NULL;

    self->first = first;
    self->last = last;
    self->display = display;

    self->base = self; // assigning reference to self to retain original functions in case they get overriden

    return 1;
}

Person* Person_new(char* first, char* last) {
    Person* self = malloc(sizeof *self);

    if(self == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(Person_init(self, first, last) == 0)
    {
        free(self);
        return NULL;
    }

    return self;
}
```

and for the `Employee` class

```
Person* Employee_new(char* first, char* last, char* company, int salary) {
    if(first == NULL || last == NULL || company == NULL)
        return NULL;

    Employee* employee = malloc(sizeof *employee);
    if(employee == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(Person_init(&employee->super, first, last) == 0)
    {
        free(employee);
        return NULL;
    }
    employee->super.display = display; // override

    employee->company = company;
    employee->salary = salary;

    return (Person *)employee;
}
```

Then you don't have to worry about freeing the base object.

---

**edit2**

*OP said in the comments**

> I'm wondering what's wrong with the freeing the base pointer, I'm assigning it right away to the new value `free(&employee->super); employee->super = *super;`

Sorry, it seem to me you don't have a real understanding of memory managment and
what the `*` dereferencing operator does.

First of all, you have **no** guarantee that after `free(ptr)` you can access
the contents of `ptr`. After the `free`, `ptr` points to an invalid location and
accessing/dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.

Secondly

```
employee->super = *Person_new(first, last);
```

is the same as doing

```
Person *tmp = Person_new(first, last);
employee->super = *tmp;
```

`*tmp` is dereferencing `tmp`, the type is `Person` not `Person*`. In C when you
do an assigment with struct objects (not pointers) you are copying bit by bit
the bit pattern into a new object. That means that the bit pattern of
`employee->super` is the same as the bit pattern of `*tmp`, but they are **not**
the sam object, the reside at different places in memory.

You can only call `free(ptr)` when `ptr` stores the address returned by either
`malloc` or `realloc`. If you do `free(&employee->super)` you are passing a
completely different address to that one that `malloc` returned in `Person_new`,
this is undefined behaviour, you cannot do that.

There is no other way for you, you **have** to store the original pointer in the
struct, that's the reason why I added the `Person *super_ref` in the struct, so
that the original pointer is not lost.

> We have a major problem, this implementation is causing recursion at

I made small changes to your code, I don't have this problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct Person Person;
typedef struct Person {
    Person *base; // reference to itself to retain reference to original function
    char* first;
    char* last;
    void (*display)(const Person *self);
    void (*destroy)(Person *self);
} Person;
Person* Person_new(char* first, char* last);

static void display(const Person *self) {
    printf("First: %s\n", self->first);
    printf("Last: %s\n", self->last);
}

static void destroy_person(Person *self)
{
    if(self == NULL)
        return;

    free(self);
}

Person* Person_new(char* first, char* last) {
    Person* self = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    self->first = first;
    self->last = last;
    self->display = display;
    self->destroy = destroy_person;

    self->base = self; // assigning reference to self to retain original functions in case they get overriden

    return self;
}

typedef struct Employee Employee;
struct Employee {
    Person super;
    char* company;
    int salary;
};
Person* Employee_new(char* first, char* last, char* company, int salary);

static void display2(const Person* self) {
    self->base->display(self->base);

    Employee *e = (Employee*) self;

    printf("Company: %s\n", e->company);
    printf("Salary: %d\n", e->salary);
}

static void destroy_employee(Person *self)
{
    if(self == NULL)
        return;

    if(self->base)
        self->base->destroy(self->base);

    free(self);
}

Person* Employee_new(char* first, char* last, char* company, int salary) {
    Employee* employee = malloc(sizeof(Employee));

    employee->super = *Person_new(first, last);
    employee->super.display = display2; // override
    employee->super.destroy = destroy_employee; // override


    employee->company = company;
    employee->salary = salary;

    return (Person*) employee;
}


int main(void)
{
    Person* person = Person_new("John", "Doe");
    Person* employee = Employee_new("Jane", "Doe", "Acme", 40000);
    person->display(person); 
    puts("---");
    employee->display(employee);

    person->destroy(person);
    employee->destroy(employee);

}
```

It prints

```
$ ./b 
First: John
Last: Doe
---
First: Jane
Last: Doe
Company: Acme
Salary: 40000
```

**edit3**

The fact that my little changes do not have the problem of endless recursion in
`display2` kept me thinking about it and I've been running the code with the
debugger to see why I didn't have the problem as well. And now I understand why
my code does not have that problem, and your's shouldn't have that as well. In
fact, I realized that there is a way of freeing the memory correctly without
have a separate member like `super_ref`.

Let me explain:

In `Employee_new` you do:

```
employee->super = *Person_new(first, last);
employee->super.display = display2; // override
```

I told you that you would be leaking memory because you lose the original
pointer that `malloc` returns. And that is true, however I failed to realize
that you have in fact a pointer pointing to the original address that `malloc`
returns: the `base` member of the `Person` struct. In `Person_new` you do

```
self->base = self;
```

and this solves the problem with the overloading and the freeing, even though we
both didn't realize it at the time.

So again, when you do

```
employee->super = *Person_new(first, last);
```

you are dereferencing the pointer returned by `malloc` and making a copy of the
object into another object. But I failed to realize is that
`employee->super->base` points to the original location returned by `malloc`.
So when you do

```
employee->super.display = display2; // override
```

you are indeed setting a new value to `employee->super.display`, but because
`employee->super` is just a copy, the original does not change and with
`employee->super->base` you get the orginal object.

That's why

```
static void display2(const Person* self) {
    self->base->display(self->base);
    ...
}
```

shouldn't do end in a recursion, because `self->display` points to `display2`,
but `self->base->display` is still unchanged and points to `display`.

And now you can use the same behaviour for destroying the Employee object.
Let's say you have `destroy` function pointer in `Person` which points to the
destroy function:

```
void destroy_person(Person *person)
{
    if(person == NULL)
        return NULL;

    free(person);
}
```

and in `Person_new` you add:

```
self->destroy = destroy_person;
```

Now you can destroy a person object by doing `person->destroy(person);`.

The `destroy` for `Employee` will look similar to `display2`:

```
void destroy_employee(Person *self)
{
    if(self == NULL)
        return;

    if(self->base)
        self->base->destroy(self->base);

    free(self);
}
```

because `self->base` is still pointing to the original object,
`self->base->destroy` points to `destroy_person`. Now in
`Employee_new` you have to add

```
employee->super.display = display2; // override
employee->super.destroy = destroy_employee; // override
```

and in `main` you just do `person->destroy(person)` and
`employee->destroy(employee);`. I've checked the code above (I've updated with
the destroy functions) with valgrind and it told me that everything was freed
correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74035/discussion-between-app2015-and-pablo).

Comment: I read your edit3, in other words are you saying that my original approach was correct? I'm confused a bit going in both directions now

Comment: @App2015 yes, your approach was correct, I didn't realize it right away, I had to step through the code with the debugger.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. I liked the fact that you have valgrind, I couldn't have it on Mac. one last favor can you download this and review if everything is intact, I've spent a great deal on this to get it right, also would you like to discuss if this is runtime or compile time polymorphism? Download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4vdpicj1aq17ao/Polymorphism.zip?dl=0

Comment: "There is one thing I don't line about" You probably mean like about?

Comment: @App2015 no, I'm not going to do that, if you have further question with changes of your new code, please create a new question with the new code, then I'll gladly take a look at that. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: ok, In my code, within `Employee_new` function, do I need to free existing super`free(&employee->super)` before assigning `employee->super = *Person_new(first, last);` to release the auto allocated sub struct value as a result of `malloc` on the parent struct. If not then why?

Comment: @App2015 **no**, why are you insisting on freeing stuff in the create function that are needed throughout the object's life span? In order to have a correct override mechanism, you need the original object with the original function pointers which you access with `self->base`. Only when the whole `Employee` object is destroyed you can free the base object. And I told you 100 times already (but you keep ignoring that), `free(&employee->super)` **is simply wrong**, because you can only pass to `free` the address that you've got from `malloc`. See my example in edit 3 on how to do it.

Comment: *do I need to free existing super ...  before assignin?* Once again, I've told you 100 times, you cannot free something and then try to access the content later.

Answer (score 2):

### Question-able shallow copy of names

Below code makes a copy of a pointer, that given OP's example, is a pointer to a *string literal* - in which case, `self->first = first; self->last = last;` both should have been `const char *`.  I would expect an allocation of memory to duplicate the *strings* with `strdup()` or its equivalent function - [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39694254/2410359).  `strdup()` is not part of the standard C library, yet commonly available.

```
// self->first = first;
// self->last = last;
self->first = strdup(first);
self->last = strdup(last);
```

Comment: sure, I'm going to edit it based on your suggestions

Comment: @App2015 please read the help section on updating your question. It's generally not allowed.

Comment: sorry about that.

Comment: @App2015 The update 1) should not have been done per this site's standards 2) `malloc(sizeof(char *) * (strlen(first) + 1));` is an excessive  allocation

Comment: what makes it excessive?

Comment: @App2015 Review why code used `sizeof(char *)` to determine the size of data pointed to by `self->first`?

Comment: thanks, I understand, question if `free(self)` on person object gets called, I assume it also free the `first` and `last` irrespective of memory allocation via `strdup` or `malloc`?